# Built-in function and user defined function different attributes

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
def f():
  pass

print("f: ", dir(f))
print("len: ", dir(len))
```

The output:

```
f:  ['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
len:  ['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Why function `f` and function `len` have different attributes? I know that `len` is built-in function, but still, why they don't have the same attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because C-defined functions are a different type, and only user-defined functions support certain functionality, like adding attributes or nesting the function definitions and referring to scoped names.

Take a look at the extra attributes a user-defined function gives you:

```
>>> sorted(set(dir(f)) - set(dir(len)))
['__annotations__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__dict__', '__get__', '__globals__', '__kwdefaults__']
```

A C-defined function will never have a closure, or globals, nor does it have bytecode, for example. Breaking each one out:

- `__annotations__`: the annotations added to a function definition; you can only do this with user-defined functions, as this is a Python syntax feature.
- `__closure__`: the list of cells taken from the scope closure; C-defined functions cannot be defined inside another function, so there is no closure for those.
- `__code__`: The Python bytecode object; C-defined functions don't have that.
- `__defaults__`: C-defined functions may have default values (keywords) but they are not defined as Python values that you can introspect.
- `__dict__`: C-defined functions cannot have arbitrary attributes set on them, while user-defined functions can.
- `__get__`: This makes a user-defined function a descriptor, making them work as methods in classes. Most C-functions don't need this.
- `__globals__`: User-defined functions are defined in modules; this points to the global namespace. C-defined functions don't have a python module namespace to point to.
- `__kwdefaults__`: like `__defaults__` but for keyword-only parameters, as a dict; again only Python functions can have these.

Comment: @thegrinner: Yes, something went weird there for a moment.